# RetroPie pre config image

Tags: retropie

I have been trying to get my retro pie working for the last couple of days and this is my last hope. I was wondering if anyone could lend me there file for retro pie that is already configured, for Gameboy advanced. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not able to share my image currently, hopefully this will help:

The GBA on RetroPie requires an additional BIOS file that does not come with the initial download. [Here is the file, gba_bin.bios, found on Google Drive.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0qPHTtuHKAhVDVj4KHcUAAyoQFghCMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fopen%3Fid%3D0B6pZyudLcTGLOUNzQXIxWUkwaEk&usg=AFQjCNHAweHAyGx9qMfAsSgQiXDmy20T7Q&bvm=bv.113370389,d.cWw%20%22The%20file,%20gba_bin.bios,%20found%20on%20Google%20Drive.)

Once downloaded, move the file to your Raspberry Pi. At this point, you must place the file into the correct directory:

```
/opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi
```

For instance, if you saved the file to a USB drive, you could copy the file over:

```
sudo cp /media/usb0/gba_bin.bios /opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi
```

As long as the ROMs and this file are now in the correct locations, you should be able to play the GBA games after you reboot.

Comment: Hey! thank you very much, I'm going to go try it right now. I knew you needed it but I didn't know that you had to put it in the emulator folder instead of the roms folder, Thank you SO much!

Comment: if you do happen to come back tonight I was wondering how do I get to the console to type ''Sudo cp'' On retro pie

Comment: No problem! If you connect a keyboard, hitting F4 will bring you out of the Emulation Station and into the LXTerminal. From there, you're working with the Pi as you would normally from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you’d want to do is perform a RetroPie Binary Update. To do that type the following in the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd RetroPie-Setup /p
pi@raspberrypi ~/RetroPie-Setup $ sudo ./retropie_setup.sh
```

Next, select Option 5: UPDATE RetroPie Binaries. Once that was done, reboot the system.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo reboot
```

For the GameBoy Advance tab to load in EmulationStation, make sure you have at least one game rom loaded in the GBA directory located at

```
/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/gba
```

GameBoy Advance also needs a bios file in order for the games to work. Copy `gba_bios.bin` into the following directory:

```
/opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi
```

Using these commands:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cp [gba_bios.bin file] /opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi
```

Now that a game ROM is in the `gba` directory and a copy of the `gba_bios.bin` bios file is in the correct location go into EmulationStation with

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ emulationstation
```

Load a GBA game and the game should play! If you are using a controller you might find out that it isn’t working. This emulator does not use the RetroArch configuration file. By default only a keyboard is set up so you will need to plug one in if you don’t already have one.

Load the emulator menu with F10 and go to the option to configure a controller. You will have to use a mix of the controller and keyboard to get all the buttons set up but once you do you can unplug the keyboard.
One thing to note is all the hotkeys that you may have set up will not work. All the options though are in the GPSP Menu system so it will just be one added step.
The input file for the controller and keyboard are located at:

```
/opt/retropie/emulators/gpsp/raspberrypi/keys.txt
```

That’s it! Now you can enjoy all your GBA games on your RaspberyPi.

<sub>[Totally not copy-pasted from here.](https://weekendengineer.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/setting-up-gameboy-advance-for-retropie/) Full credits go to the original author. I do not, in any way, claim that this is my work.</sub>